# How can I view the object hierarchy in XCode 4 like XCode 3 does?

Tags: iphone, xcode, hierarchy, xib

In Information Builder, I need to view/navigate all the objects in a the XIB and like to use the object hierarchy view in Xcode 3.  However, in XCode 4, it just show the top level objects, but not the child objects. How can I view them all in XCode 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also simply drag the object view window from the right side of the window.  It will then show all the objects and their hierarchy.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the other answers, that helped me.  For future answer seekers, it looked a bit different for me in xcode 4.2.   Pressing the grey"play" button in the bottom left corner poped out the hierarchy.

[image: xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Click on the arrow in the lower left of the gutter that shows the objects[image]

Comment: thank you for answering this :-) the interface is NOT intuitive